# Multiple date formats in tbl_spark in R. I want to change all the date formats to one format (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: r, sparklyr

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

date1 <- data.frame(DATE1 =c ("12-01-2020","2020-12-24",
  "14-May-2020","19/3/2020 14:32:15",
  "2020-09-08","05/05/2020"),
  NAME1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
tbl <- copy_to(sc, date1)
```

The end result date should be in 'dd-mmm-yyyy' format.

Tried this

```
 lubridate::parse_date_time(tbl %>% select(DATE1) , c('dmY', 'Ymd', 'dmYT'))
```

[1] NA NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in R, can you check if it does in `sparklyr` ?

```
as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(date1$DATE1, c('dmY', 'Ymd', 'dmYT')))
#[1] "2020-01-12" "2020-12-24" "2020-05-14" "2020-03-19" "2020-09-08" "2020-05-05"
```

Comment: @Let'sCode and without `as.Date` works? `lubridate::parse_date_time(date1$DATE1, c('dmY', 'Ymd', 'dmYT'))`

Comment: The result is POSIXct of length 0.

Comment: I think in sparklyr, the '$' doesnt work for extract a column

Comment: @Let'sCode Try `lubridate::parse_date_time(date1 %>% pull(DATE1), c('dmY', 'Ymd', 'dmYT'))`